# Why do I get two answer when calculating this integral from two ways?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Assuming $a(t)=a_0\sin(\omega t)$, $v(0)=0$ and $x(0)=0$.

I hope you know about basic relation between position, velocity and acceleration.
They are derivatives of the proceeding one.

I went on calculating like so:

$$\require{cancel} (\mathbf{1})\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ v(t)=\int a_0 \sin(u)\frac{du}{\omega}=\frac{a_0}{\omega}\cdot-\cos(\omega t)+\cancelto{0}{C}=\color{blue}{-\frac{a_0}{\omega}\cos(\omega t)}$$

$$(\mathbf{2})\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ v(t)=\int_0^ta_0 \sin(\omega t')dt'=a_0\int_0^t\sin(u)\frac{du}{\omega}=\frac{a_0}{\omega}\left[-\cos(\omega t)\cancelto{+1}{-(-\cos(0)})\right]$$

$$\implies v(t)=\color{red}{\frac{a_0}{\omega}(1-\cos(\omega t))}$$

$$\color{red}{\frac{a_0}{\omega}(1-\cos(\omega t))}\neq\color{blue}{-\frac{a_0}{\omega}\cos(\omega t)}$$

Comment: Because you take constant to be $0$ in the first case and $1$ in the second. Why? In physics terms, you start time at different instances in the first and second case

Comment: @You'reInMyEye . In the second method there is no constant because it's a difinite integral.

Comment: In you first line you can't take the constant to be $0$ since you want to have $0=v(0)=\frac{a_0}{\omega}\cdot (-\cos(\omega \cdot 0))+C$.

Comment: @AHB, you chose the second limit to be $0$. In the first case you chose the constant to be $0$. Both times you were solving the same integral, but picked different limits. Or alternatively, if you were solving indefinite integral in the first case, you should've left the constant undefined

Comment: I must say, great job at formatting!

Comment: @You'reInMyEye I put the picture because I didn't know how to format some parts. Still you can see some parts are ommited or I have written them in an alternative way using the Mathjax's I knew. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line you get
$$
v(t)=\frac{a_0}{\omega}\cdot (-\cos(\omega \cdot t))+C
$$ then by putting $t=0$, you have $v(0)=0$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
&0=\frac{a_0}{\omega}\cdot (-\cos(\omega \cdot 0))+C
\\\\&0=-\frac{a_0}{\omega}+C
\\\\&C=\frac{a_0}{\omega}.
\end{align}
$$

Then there is *no more contradiction* with your second computation.